# "net user administrator /active:Yes" returns "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator

I need to give the **administrator** 's authorizations to delete a folder, I'm on Windows 7 ultimate x64.

To do that I run **cmd**.exe and run the command below:

```
net user administrator /active:Yes
```

However, I get the following:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

I already run the `net localgroup Administrators` to check either my account is listed among the administrator members, and it is.

**Why do I get this error and how can I give the Administrator's authorization to delete my folder?**

Comment: You need your account to be in the Administrators group to be able to modify the user account. If you don't have an administrator account then you will need to know who can or, ultimately, resort to, say, a tool to forcibly enable the account by modifying the registry (e.g. Offline NT Password & Registry Editor).

Comment: First of all it is `net user administrator /active:Yes` (mind the `/` instead of the `\ `), and you have to run it from an **elevated** command prompt.

Comment: Thank you. In any case I've been trying both with the "\" and the "/" slash and I got the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I'm seeing here that could cause this:

1. You are not part of the administrators group or you do not have administrator permissions on the box.
2. You need to run command prompt from an elevated permission level.

Easiest way to check if you are an administrator on your machine is to list all administrators on the box:

```
net localgroup Administrators
```

If you are not listed there, you are not an administrator. It will also list the groups that are admins on the machine. So for example, if I was a part of the `Domain Admins` group and the policy for `Domain Admins` was administrator access on the machines, then I would have admin access without being listed in the output of the command.

To check what groups you are a part of, you can use `whoami /groups` which will list all groups and aliases that the logged in user is a part of. And based off of all of this data, you'll then know if you are an admin or not.

Also, as [Eugen said in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1035082/net-user-administrator-activeyes-gives-me-error-5-access-is-denied#comment1444876_1035082), make sure you're using the right slashes in your commands.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I run the `net localgroup Administrators` and well, I'm among its members.
Furthermore I get the same error even when I use the "/" slash.

Comment: How about part 2: AQre you running it from an elevated command prompt? e.g. right click cmd and select run as admin. Answer yes to the UAC question. Of control-shift-enter from the startmenu after start run, or ...)

Comment: I just run cmd.exe as administrator, re-typed the command and it did work, now I succeded in deleting the folder, thank you.