# System error 5 has occurred even as admin - (cmd) Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, administrator

My system is Windows 10 Pro x64, with the latest updates applied.

When I try to execute any "net" command in cmd (eg: net stop TeamViewer, net users, etc') I get the error "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."

I have researched for hours and did every possible solution I saw mentioned anywhere but still no luck.
Here are a few facts:

1. I opened the cmd with admin rights (see screenshot below)
2. I am the sole PC user with full admin rights.
3. This happens even if I disable Windows Firewall.
4. My UAC is disabled and in the registry, EnableLUA is set to 0.
5. Also in Windows Built-in administrator account, the issue happens.

How can I give myself access to run net commands?

(note: I know there are similar questions on this forum to my question but none of those answers helped my case.)

[image: Error Screenshot]

UPDATES:

1. Please don't recommend answers from posts such as [net-user-administrator-activeyes-returns-system-error-5-has-occurred-acces](https://superuser.com/questions/1035082/net-user-administrator-activeyes-returns-system-error-5-has-occurred-acces) since I already explained in my bullet points why the answers there don't apply for me.
2. I tried to rebuild my machine using the Media Creation Link as suggested in the comments (repair in-place). Took 5 hours but was not successful and I cannot try again with a boot disk (I recall trying this a few years ago and know it won't help).

[image: Couln't install Windows 10]

**In reply to @frank:**

*does this affect all services or just select ones?*

All services. Also, any "net" command, even if it's not related to a service (as mentioned in my question)

*Can you start and stop the service in services.msc?*

Yes. But I need to be able to also stop services via a cmd command to create a batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["net user administrator /active:Yes" returns "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."](https://superuser.com/questions/1035082/net-user-administrator-activeyes-returns-system-error-5-has-occurred-acces)

Comment: No. Everything in that post (and all other similar questions on this form) I have made bullet points in my question which explains why those answers don't apply to me. For example, the answer there says "You are not part of the Administrators group or you do not have administrator permissions... You need to run command prompt from an elevated permission level." You will see in my bullet points that this answer doesn't help me. Also, it says there "Easiest way to check if you are an administrator on your machine is to use "net localgroup Administrator" - but I can't use any "net" command.

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  

Follow this with sfc  /scannow   Restart when done and test.

If this fails, make a temporary new user account, log into the new account and test your work in the new account

Comment: Did dism and sfc last week (routine checks) and all is fine there. Just created a new administrator account to test but same error on the new account as well.

Comment: So you need to rebuild the machine using the Media Creation Link.  Use the second link, run the Repair in place, at the appropriate spot, Keep Everything (try that). Complete the repair and test again.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: That is extreme and would be the LAST thing to try.

Comment: No. Repair Rebuilds are simple. Follow the steps and wait for the paint to dry. I have done many of them. Not extreme in any way whatever. Format and reinstall is the extreme last step.

Comment: does this affect all services, or just select ones? also note, Error 5 is often misleading. can you start and stop the service in services.msc?

Comment: I replied to all the above as an update in my question.

Comment: Do you have the same issue in PowerShell?

Comment: @Didier yes, just tried. Same thing.

Comment: Any chance a GPO could restrict the use of command line, even for admins? If you launch the following command in PS, what do you get? Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -AutoSize | EDIT: I suppose you've tried also in Safe Mode?

Comment: Have you checked if your PC is set on the right time/time zone?

Comment: @Didier Get-ExecutionPolicy is all "undefined." Timezone is set to auto and correct. Tried in safemode, same issue.

Comment: PS return is good, in the sense that it doesn't show any restrictions on your account. You're going to think I'm crazy, but would you indulge me for two minutes, tops? Download the portable version of Command Prompt for Windows (here: https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/command_prompt_portable), run it as it is standalone, only comes with a .bat file for added arguments, and see if you can unlock the "net users" command? (That's the easiest one to check, as it doesn't need to be run as admin) Just to check.

Comment: Almost forgot: Your PC is clean? No viruses, malware of any kind?

Comment: @Didier "net users" works with the portable app. But it doesn't work to stop a service.

Comment: @Didier Clean as a whistle.

Comment: OK, good to know. It's one of the obvious reasons why your admin account could be messed with in the first place: to prevent you from deleting entrenched malware via admin commands. As for the portable command line working, it's normal because it bypasses the one installed by Windows. Have you tried to right-click and run it as an administrator just to see if it works? It won't show the usual "C:\Windows\system32\>" prompt, just "C:\>", but I tried on my own PC, and it works. EDIT: under "netplwiz" > Advanced, you can get a reading of user accounts properties (opens lusmgr.msc, in fact).

Comment: @Didier UPDATE! Powershell DOES stop services when 1: is run as admin. 2: Using the PS command, "stop-service [service-name]. So this is actually enough for me. In my batch file I write "@echo off PowerShell.exe -Command stop-service ****" and make a shortcut to it. In the properties of the shortcut I set to run as admin and walla, it works! Since you thought of the PS idea, please write this as an answer so I can accept it. (although it doesn't solve the cmd issue)

Comment: I'm glad you're back in business, but we all floated so many ideas in this thread, I don't know where to start... :-) I'll try and think of something, but your case was pretty unique: Error 5 can happen for a lot of reasons (time badly set, virus, corrupted account token, etc...), so to be honest, I don't know what made PS suddenly take commands it was spitting out moments earlier. Lemme think of something! Cheers mate!

Comment: I had not tried the PS script before. I used "net stop" in PS which does NOT work. Only the PS script works in PS.

Comment: This is my final script I run PS as an admin in an AHK file to close TeamViewer service without a shortcut: Run *runas PowerShell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "stop-service TeamViewer"

Comment: I've got to assume somthing is wrong with the net.exe

Comment: Looks like you run `net` command in _Windows Terminal_. Run _pure_ `cmd.exe` as administrator instead.

Comment: @JosefZ Nice thinking but I don't have the Windows terminal app. The title bar might look like it because I use stardock groupy.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the answer I quote @ZviTwersky (thanks to @Didier for the idea):

"Powershell DOES stop services when
1: is run as admin.
2: Using the PS command, "stop-service [service-name]".

So this is actually enough for me. In my batch file I write "@echo off PowerShell.exe -Command stop-service ****" and make a shortcut to it. In the properties of the shortcut I set to run as admin and walla, it works! Since you thought of the PS idea, please write this as an answer so I can accept it. (although it doesn't solve the cmd issue)."

P.S. Unfortunately it did not work for me because powershell complains about the name